# Spring-security-4.0.1-RELEASE` & spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE xsd issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, xsd

I am using `Spring-security-4.0.1-RELEASE` & spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE`

Here is my .xsd declarations

Spring security

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
```

Application context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">
```

dispatcher servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

When I run app it shows `org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ConfigFiles/Security.xml]`

How to know which xsd i should use while changing version

Comment: Simply remove `-3.0`, `-3.2`, etc. from the declarations.

Comment: but i have version `4.0.1` & `4.1.7`

Comment: That is fine.  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` will pick up the appropriate version if there is only one `spring-context.jar` on the classpath.  Similarly, `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd` will pick up the appropriate version if there is only one `spring-security-context.jar` on the classpath.

Comment: here is the issue i found if remove version number from all xsd & use   `<spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>  <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>` it works well but for the above spring versions its not working

Comment: Works fine for me.  Download [this project](http://ge.tt/3wbRafK2/v/0?c) and then run `mvn clean tomcat7:run`.  The server starts without errors.  See the files in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: The problem i am facing is i have a login form. If i use 3.2.8 it works fine with my custom login form. but if use 4.0.1 & 4.1.7 it shows spring default login form insted of my custom login form

Comment: That is a different issue.  See the Spring 4.x migration guide for details.  A lot of things have changed between 3.x and 4.x, including the URLs to the login and logout actions.